# Unable to find "testdisk" or "testdisk-dbg" packages in 15.04

Tags: command-line, ppa, software-sources

Hello after a first installation 15.04 working at best, even
better than manjaro + now it seems that there were some attacks (as usual) and by this the ppa or sources.lists are a bit affected + how do I install now `testdisk` ?! - apparently `testdisk` is not part of Vivid ?!

Answer (score 4):

`testdisk` is well available in Vivid repos: [testdisk (6.14-3build2) [universe]](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/testdisk)

Just enable the universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

Comment: You could use just `sudo add-apt-repository  universe` no need for full link see `man add-apt-repository` 3rd form.